# Usando jQuery Validation Engine e validação de CPF

Tags: jquery, validação, jquery-validation-engine

Eu estou usando o jQuery Validation Engine com arquivo de traduções para Português. Adicionei no JavaScript a seguinte linha:

```
"cpf": {
    "regex": /^\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\/\d{4}\-\d{2}$/,
     "alertText": "* CPF inválido"
 }
```

```
Class="validate[required,custom[cpf]]
```

Porém esta validação não é muito eficiente, já que só verifica a quantidade de caracteres.

Como posso fazer um método para validar o CPFe continuar utilizando o Validation Engine desta forma?

Answer (score 5):

Validação de CPF se dá através da implementação de um algorítimo.

Com ERs talvez até seja possível através do metacaractere modernoso [(?{codigo})](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/modernosos-codigo.html#3_5_9), mas eu acho bastante improvável, além de engessar sua Aplicação.

O melhor a se fazer é adicionar um novo validador.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("cpf", function(value, element) {
   value = jQuery.trim(value);

    value = value.replace('.','');
    value = value.replace('.','');
    cpf = value.replace('-','');
    while(cpf.length < 11) cpf = "0"+ cpf;
    var expReg = /^0+$|^1+$|^2+$|^3+$|^4+$|^5+$|^6+$|^7+$|^8+$|^9+$/;
    var a = [];
    var b = new Number;
    var c = 11;
    for (i=0; i<11; i++){
        a[i] = cpf.charAt(i);
        if (i < 9) b += (a[i] * --c);
    }
    if ((x = b % 11) < 2) { a[9] = 0 } else { a[9] = 11-x }
    b = 0;
    c = 11;
    for (y=0; y<10; y++) b += (a[y] * c--);
    if ((x = b % 11) < 2) { a[10] = 0; } else { a[10] = 11-x; }

    var retorno = true;
    if ((cpf.charAt(9) != a[9]) || (cpf.charAt(10) != a[10]) || cpf.match(expReg)) retorno = false;

    return this.optional(element) || retorno;

}, "Informe um CPF válido");


$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#meuForm").validate({
      rules: {
          cpf: {cpf: true, required: true}
      },
      messages: {
         cpf: { cpf: 'CPF inválido'}
      }
      ,submitHandler:function(form) {
         alert('ok');
      }
   });
});
```

Exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5wkjbu8c/)

Comment: Não usei o snippet embutido porque está dando um erro no console, amanhã eu vejo o que pode ser. E quanto ao algorítimo, eu peguei um aleatório na Internet, não cheguei a otimizar.

Comment: Ah sim, mas ja tenho bem mais que 10 "obsoletos" na lista :) - Se bem que o chapéu atual acho que foi feito sob medida pro meu "avatar".

Comment: Eu tive alguns problemas no console, como "Cannot read property 'call' of undefined. Exception ocurred when checking element", mas resolvi declarando as variáveis. var cpf = value.replace('-',''); (add o var), e adicionei as linhas abaixo de " var c":
var i;
var x;
var y;

Answer (score 3):

Função bem simples retirada de http://geradorderg.com/logica-verificador-de-cpf/
Para utilizar, basta enviar o valor numérico do CPF.

```
function validarCPF(input_cpf){
 //get input
 if(input_cpf){
   var input=input_cpf.toString();

   var numeros=[];
   var pesos_A=[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2];
   var pesos_B=[11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2];
   var sum=0;
   var x1=0;
   var x2=0;

   for(var i=0;i=2){
     x1=11-mod;
   }

   //calcula digito 2
   sum=0;
   for(var i=0;i=2){
     x2=11-mod;
   }

   if(x1==input[9] && x2==input[10]){
     return true;
   }else{
     return false;
   }
   }else{
     return false;
   }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

No HTML coloque o "id"  do campo input do CPF de "cpf" e adicione o script abaixo. Quando o campo do CPF perder o foco a funcao abaixo será executada:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    //Executa a requisição quando o campo username perder o foco
    $('#cpf').blur(function()
    {
        var cpf = $('#cpf').val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').toString();

        if( cpf.length == 11 )
        {
            var v = [];

            //Calcula o primeiro dígito de verificação.
            v[0] = 1 * cpf[0] + 2 * cpf[1] + 3 * cpf[2];
            v[0] += 4 * cpf[3] + 5 * cpf[4] + 6 * cpf[5];
            v[0] += 7 * cpf[6] + 8 * cpf[7] + 9 * cpf[8];
            v[0] = v[0] % 11;
            v[0] = v[0] % 10;

            //Calcula o segundo dígito de verificação.
            v[1] = 1 * cpf[1] + 2 * cpf[2] + 3 * cpf[3];
            v[1] += 4 * cpf[4] + 5 * cpf[5] + 6 * cpf[6];
            v[1] += 7 * cpf[7] + 8 * cpf[8] + 9 * v[0];
            v[1] = v[1] % 11;
            v[1] = v[1] % 10;

            //Retorna Verdadeiro se os dígitos de verificação são os esperados.
            if ( (v[0] != cpf[9]) || (v[1] != cpf[10]) )
            {
                alert('CPF inválido: ' + cpf);

                $('#cpf').val('');
                $('#cpf').focus();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert('CPF inválido:' + cpf);

            $('#cpf').val('');
            $('#cpf').focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando o **jQuery Validation Engine** existe uma regra (rule) chamada `remote`, que:

> [...] realiza uma verificação remota com a url e com o valor informado no campo, assim, se a resposta para a requisição de validação for false, então o Validation entende que a informação no campo não é válida, agora caso a resposta for true então a informação é válida. Por exemplo: verificar se o CFP já existe na aplicação;

**Fonte**: [Validação com jQuery](http://www.devmedia.com.br/validacao-com-jquery-como-usar-o-plugin-validation/33670)

Espero ter ajudado ;)

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar um verificador customizado com função:

```
"cpf": {
       "func": function(field, rules, i, options) {
            var regex = /^\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\/\d{4}\-\d{2}$/;
            if (!regex.test(field.val())
                return false;

            // outras verificações, tais como:
            //  - dígitos verificadores

            return true;
       },
       "alertText": "CPF inválido"
},
```